# Let $F$ be a subfield of $R$, and let $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ where $\alpha > 0$ be an element of $F$, but $\sqrt{\alpha} \not \in F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

As part of a question, my homework defines this field:

> Let $F$ be a subfield of $\Bbb{R}$, and let $\alpha \in \Bbb{R}$ where $\alpha > 0$
>   be an element of $F$, with $\sqrt{\alpha} \not \in F$.

If $\alpha \in F$, then $\alpha \cdot \alpha \in F$. That means, by definition of multiplication on $\Bbb{R}$, which holds for $F$, that $\alpha^2 \in F$. But if $\alpha^2 \in F$, then $\sqrt{\alpha^2} \not \in F$. Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: No, in the exercise they tell you there is a specific element $\alpha\in F$ such that $\sqrt{\alpha}\notin F$. It doesn't mean this is true for all the elements in $F$.

Comment: I do not see a contradiction,  supposing that $\alpha\in F$...

Answer (score 1):

For such questions an example can help a lot. The canonical choice here is to take $F=\Bbb Q$ and $\alpha=2$. Then $\sqrt{2}\not\in F$ as required. Now where is your contradiction? "But if $\alpha^2=4\in \Bbb Q$, then $\sqrt{\alpha^2}\not\in F$." Well, no, because $\alpha^2=4$ and $\sqrt{4}=2\in F$. We only have $\sqrt{2}\not\in F$.